# Unable to get data from two tables in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am doing project in laravel.

**Database Table 1**

```
user_verification
------------------------------------------
'id', 'user_id', 'verified', 'verified_by'
```

**Database Table 2**

```
user
-----------------------------
'id', 'name', 'email', 'pass'
```

I want to get data as all users which are verified('verified' = 1) and name of user('verified_by' is user id from user table) who does verification.

My controller method is like,

```
public function verifiedProviders(){
    //$user_data = sql query goes here...
    return view('display',compact('user_data '));
}
```

**for example:**,

I want to display in blade file as follow

```
name:abc,
email:abc@gmail.com,
verified by: name (id present in *verified_by* field) from *user* table.
```

I am not getting how to get and display this data in laravel's blade file. How to use relationships eloquent method or database query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where's the code you've been working?

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: It should be `return view('display', compact('user_data '));`

Comment: oh it's by mistake, i'll edit the code

Comment: Is id from db2 is equal to user_id of db1?

Comment: Where's your attempted sql query?

Comment: @Amarja are you using Eloquent Relationships? https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships
If not then please read the doc in this link and implement.

Answer (score 0):

```
User::select('name', 'email', 'u2.name as verified_by_name')
    ->join('user_verification', 'user_verification.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
    ->join('user u2', 'user_verification.verified_by', '=', 'u2.id')
    ->all(); // I guess
```

Of course you may want to limit your query to return only the first 25 results and display them, etc.

References:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#joins
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#selects

Comment: Your "user" table should be "users" btw.  Laravel standard is to use singular for the model classes and plural for the table names.

Comment: OK, I'll change it to users table but after using above code I am getting error as, 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()'

Comment: Try get () instead of all (). You may also want to add some limit clauses